# layered pdf page to multiple images

Tags: html, pdf, imagemagick, poppler

I would like to convert a single page pdf into multiple layered images.

For example the library pdf2htmlEX converts a pdf to html by making a single background png image and placing text on that image(the text is in unicode).

i would like to do something similar, Separate the background image and other portions but all in image format.

I have looked into poppler libraries and some other solutions, but couldnt find anything useful.

A url at which someone else wants the same thing done.

[How do extract text layer and background layer from pdf?](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=13106&sid=8ce66dd860c7c282caf61299150433e9#p44039)